# LaTeX Code for Study-Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, stix

I'd like to have the TeX code of this matrix in the photo, please:

[Study-Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Az1m.jpg)

[image]
I state that I know something of `nicematrix` and `tikz`-packages and I use `stix`.

I'd like to have the TeX code of the same matrix with the difference that `pmatrix` is contained in a box, this is, I'd like the TeX code of the photo with completed (closed) box and the TeX code of `\diagbox{A_i}{A_j}` only, too.

I hope have been clear.

I've started with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmat}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=5mm]
\diagbox{\scriptstyle A_i}{\scriptstyle A^j} 
\Block[hvlines]{1-4}{}
\Block[hvlines]{4-1}{}
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
\boxed{\SubMatrix({2-2}{4-4})[xshift=-0.85mm]
\begin{tikzpicture} [dashed,shorten > = 2mm, shorten < = 2mm]
  \draw (3-|2) -- (3-|5) ; 
  \draw (4-|2) -- (4-|5) ;
  \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
  \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{NiceMatrix}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried with `nicematrix`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=5mm]
\diagbox{\scriptstyle A_i}{\scriptstyle A^j} 
\Block[hvlines]{1-4}{}
\Block[hvlines]{4-1}{}
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({2-2}{4-4})[xshift=-0.85mm]
  \begin{tikzpicture} [dashed,shorten > = 2mm, shorten < = 2mm]
  \draw (3-|2) -- (3-|5) ; 
  \draw (4-|2) -- (4-|5) ;
  \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
  \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]